# How to adjust actor z index based on x?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

Im working on a card game using libgdx and scene2d.
My card class extends the Image actor class. Im trying to find a way to set the order of how my cards are drawn based on their x position when dragged.

[image]

So i tried:

```
@Override
public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
     float sx = event.getStageX();
     float sy = event.getStageY();
     if(sx - offsetX > 0 && sy - offsetY > 0){
       event.getTarget().setPosition(sx - offsetX, sy - offsetY);
       c.setZIndex((int) sx);
    }               
}
```

This wont work because apparently, the zindex is bound to the number of actors in the stage/group. So basically the index should be 0-4. My next approach was to divide the screen width by 5 and set that to the zindex. It works fine if the cards are separated evenly across the whole width. But if the cards are compressed in the middle, they dont look good. 2 to 3 cards fall in the middle, and the last dragged one is the one drawn on top of the others. Which i dont want.

My last approach was to order all my cards by their xposition and loop through them giving z-index. And this works like i want but i find it slow (when all the other stuff are added in the mix)

So is there anyway i can set z-index relative to x-position without looping through the actors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have an array of initial positions of all your cards. Whenever drag happens, re-shuffle your array based from the drag method you already have. Draw the cards using the positions stored in your array from 0 to length - 1 where first card's position is at index 0 and the last one is at length of array minus 1.

Or - use [Group](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Group.html). Add group in draw order. You can swap actors in a group. Swap the cards based from drag events.

Comment: meaning i still would have to loop through that array (of points)? my question was how to do it without looping through it.

About the Group's swap function, ill give this a try.. But then again, i would have to find the actor to swap with.. :/ can i do this without looping through all of the actors?

Comment: You are underestimating the power of hardware. If you have one hundred actors and you loop thorugh the array (Remember your array is very light. All it contains is vectors. Vector2 posArray[]), this will not make anything fall apart. No matter what- you still have to tell libGDX to draw. Hence, libgdx has to iterate through the actors.

Comment: @noisyass2 Try benchmarking. I bet the first suggestion of using array will be much faster.

Comment: Im not actually "underestimating", im just finding a 'faster' approach to this seemingly simple task. As i mentioned in the question, it does get slow when i loop through the actors.. But you are right, looping through an array of points would be faster.

Comment: @noisyass2 I understand totally what you mean. I go through it everyday after work as I am also making a game. Try benchmarking and see the difference. :)